# How to parse through data from a firebase cloud function?

Tags: javascript, flutter, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

goal:
when a "user rating" is updated,
I want to get the new rating, and calculate the new user rating average ( very easy )

```
exports.onUserRatingUpdate = functions.firestore
    .document("user rating/{docId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, eventContext)=>{
      const snapData = change.after.data();
      const userIdReceivingRating = snapData["User id getting rating"];

      // get all userRatingAssociated with user
     
      const userRatingList = await admin.firestore()
          .collection("user rating")
          .where("User id getting rating", "==", userIdReceivingRating ).get();
    
          userRatingList.forEach(doc=>{
            console.log( "doc");
            console.log(doc)
            console.log('doc.document');
            console.log(doc.document);
          })


    });
```

The column name in 'user rating' that has the data that I want is 'User rating'

the issue that I am having is that I am not able to get a handle on the data ( see image )

I can print the data snapshot, but I cant get the data that I need. I am super close I know it but I cant get this last step to work :(

[image: firebase logs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer::

```
const userRatingList = await admin.firestore()
      .collection("user rating")
      .where("User id getting rating", "==", userIdReceivingRating ).get();

      userRatingList.forEach(doc=>{

    
        console.log('payload: '+doc.data()["User rating"])
      })
```